# In symfony, how to define a default value as empty array in yaml file?

Tags: symfony1, yaml

In symfony1, in yaml file how can i set an empty array?

```
# app.yml
all:
    test:
        example: // empty array here
```

so when i

```
<?php echo sfConfig::get('app_test_example');?>
```

it returns `array();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
# app.yml
all:
    test:
        example: []
```